# Sinch Libraries for ARM Platform

Tags: sinch

I'm trying to use the sinch sdk on a android app using the emulators that comes in android studio and I having this problem: INSTALL_FAILED_NO_MATCHING_ABIS

I know is because the so libraries were not compile for the ARM platform. Is there a way you can complie them for this platform and upload the file somewhere?

Thanks

Comment: Why don't you do it yourself?

Answer (score 3):

The Sinch SDK for Android is compiled for ARM, both armeabi and armeabi-v7, however, it is not built for x86. Please make sure that your project is set up correctly to include the .so files.